# How to install memcached on windows 7 + PHP 5.6.1

Tags: php, memcached

I am having an incredibly hard time installing memcached. I went through a number of answers here on stackoverflow, as well as a couple of guides on other sites and I just cannot do it.

I've gotten to a point where I've installed memcached as a service and I have it running ( or at least so I think ). Following the baby-steps on [this](http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine) article. However when I try to instantiate `new Memcache` or `new Memcached` I get class not found. So then I went to search for memcached options in `php.ini` and had 0 matches on a search for `memcached`. I manually added `extension=php_memcached.dll` among the other extension declarations but then I have to have a `dll` *which I cannot find anywhere*! Why don't they just put `dll`s on the php site? I found some `dll` for PHP version 5.4.0 but I received error "Compiled with old API key" or something of this nature.

Can someone please guide me through this hell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MemcacheD is a daemon and it seems like you have installed it as a service already. Now you need to setup Memcahce PHP extension, so it will work as client for MemcacheD daemon. You need to search for php_memcache.dll (no D letter on the end). You can find it here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

Comment: Jesus, I've landed on that page, I have visited links.. Anyway, I suppose `5.x` after `3.0.8` stands for php version. I have `x86` architecture but there are two files for `x86`, ts and nts. I have no clue what those stand for, which one should i get?

Comment: I risked with `ts` and it seems to be working. Still curious to find out what these stand for though.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: ts = thread safe, nts = not thread safe. [See more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Comment: Where should the downloaded files be put?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com been a while but better late than never, you need to put the `dll` in php's extensions folder, I believe it was `php/ext` but could be wrong.

Comment: Install dll from the link get **memcache** not **memcached**